# Iterate over JSON object and gather model values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send an ajax get request to receive all of the entries in one of my tables in the database as a JSON object.

After retrieving this, I am trying to iterate over all of the objects and compare the objects ID, to a local ID.

If there is a match, I want to set some html text boxes to their values, but I can't get it to work.

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/AllEvents",
    data: calEvent.id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var obj = response[i];

            if (obj.ID == calEvent.id)
            {
                document.getElementById('updateID').value = obj.ID;
                document.getElementById('updateType').value = obj.EventType;
                document.getElementById('updateDuration').value = obj.Hours;
                break;
            }
        }
    },
```

**AllEvents:**

```
public JsonResult AllEvents(double? start, double? end)
{
    var eventList = new List<object>();

    foreach (Event ev in db.Events)
    {
        eventList.Add(ev);
    }

    return Json(eventList.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Event Model:**

```
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date.")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[Required]
[EnumDataType(typeof(EventType), ErrorMessage = "Submitted value is not valid.")]
[Display(Name = "Type")]
public EventType? EventType { get; set; }

[Required]
public double Hours { get; set; }

[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you `console.log(obj)` to see whats in there? Have you tried `obj.ID.toString() == calEvent.id`? I don't see anything wrong with your code. Might as well be a type thingy.

Comment: Your code is not making sense. Your `AllEvents()` method has parameters for `start` and `end` but you never post any values for them, and you never use them in the method anyway. All you post is the value of `calEvent.id` which is just thrown away. And why would you return all the data in your data base when all you want are the properties for one row?

Comment: Best guess is that your method should be `AllEvents(int ID)` which returns only the data for that ID, - e.g. `db.Events.Where(e.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();` and the ajax should be `data: { ID: calEvent.id },`

Comment: @StephenMuecke the start and end parameters were from copying and pasting a previous method of mine - just a mistake. I have updated my code to reflect this (will add in the OP now), but I'm just confused on how JSONs and ajax work. How do I send the event object back and then access its fields?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming all you want to do is pass an ID of the Event, and then update the form controls for the `EventType` and `Hours` properties based on the Event?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes - I want to pass an ID to the server from the client side. Find the Event in the database with this ID and then send that whole event back. Then, on the client side I want to set some text boxes with the Event's field values. For example, as shown above, I want to set the 'updateType' textbox to the EventType field of the Event that was retrieved.

Comment: Your updated code should do that, although I would change it to return an anonymous object containing only the 2 values you need (`EventType` and `Hours`) - there is no point sending extra data across the wire that you then just throw away.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it still doesn't appear to be working - my text boxes still aren't being populated. I know the HTML side of things is correct, am I returning the correct thing in my FindEvent() method? Also, how do I return an anonymous object with the said 2 values? Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: `var data = new { EventType = ev.EventType.ToString(), Hours = ev.Hours }; return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. If the textboxes are not being updated, start by checking that `ev` is not `null` (you should be checking for `null` otherwise you will be throwing exceptions)

Comment: Have just seen the lastest edit. The code will work fine assuming `Event` is not `null`. What if any errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: I've managed to pass an anonymous object with these 2 values - was simpler than I thought (same as what you have) - I just can't access the values in this object. I've checked ev and it is definitely not null, although in the developer console it says: GET http://localhost:port/Home/FindEvent?ID=3 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106908/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-james-lloyd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Stephen, I managed to get this working with the following:

**FindEvent:**

```
public JsonResult FindEvent(int ID)
{
    Event ev = db.Events.Where(e => e.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

    object eventObject = new
    {
        hours = ev.Hours.ToString(),
        eventType = ev.EventType.ToString()
    };

    return Json(eventObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FindEvent", "Event")',
            data: { ID: calEvent.id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                document.getElementById('updateID').value = calEvent.id;
                document.getElementById('updateType').value = response.eventType;
                document.getElementById('updateDuration').value = response.hours;
            },

            error: function() {
                // Handle error
            }
        });
```